# Cosa significa "rimuovere" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel libro *Le certezze del dubbio* di Goliarda Sapienza ho letto questa frase:

> O sei di quelle che vanno solo al bar Euclide e *rimuovono* continuamente che a due passi c'è il malfamato Bar del Metrò?

Non riesco a capire quale sia il significato del verbo "rimuovere" in questa frase. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo caso "[rimuovere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimuovere/)" significa "dimenticare", e sottintende anche una certa predisposizione al farlo, il tutto per una più o meno lontana analogia col processo di rimozione inteso in senso psicoanalitico; citando Treccani:

> 3. In psicanalisi, respingere ed escludere dalla coscienza, mediante il processo della rimozione (v.), contenuti che potrebbero costituire fonte di angoscia e senso di colpa per il soggetto (v. rimozione, n. 2). ◆ Part. pass. rimòsso (ant. anche rimòto), anche come agg. (rovistare tra le macerie rimosse), spec. nella terminologia psicanalitica freudiana, riferito a ciò che è oggetto di rimozione: impulso, ricordo, pensiero rimosso (e assol., come s. m., il rimosso). Nell’uso ant. e letter., anche con il sign. di «lontano»: Già eravam da la selva rimossi Tanto ... (Dante: qui però eravam rimossi può essere inteso come forma di trapassato prossimo intr.); talora con uso avverbiale, e quindi invar.: ivi forse una balestrata rimosso dall’altre abitazioni ... comperò una possessione (Boccaccio).

Comment: @DaG Grazie, purtroppo a scrivere in due lingue va a finire che uno si trascina dietro in una i termini propri di quell'altra.

Comment: Certo, @kos, scusa la pignoleria, ma almeno qui lascio quasi libero sfogo alla mia pedanteria linguistica (poi chissà quante ne combino io senza accorgermene).

Comment: @DaG Nemmeno tanto pignoleria visto che "quotare" è certamente un verbo ma quella intesa da me non è certo un'accezione esistente (almeno che io sappia) ma piuttosto un inglesismo inventato di sana pianta dopo i mesi passati a scrivere su Stack Exchange. Comunque per quanto mi riguarda, visto lo scopo di questo sito (e la filosofia di Stack Exchange che promuove gli edits ai post altrui), se vedi che un mio post può essere migliorato sentiti pure libero di farlo.